# IntelliJ fails to install on Oracle Linux

Tags: intellij-idea, sh, locks, oraclelinux

OS: Oracle Linux Server release 7.8

Steps to reproduce

1. I downloaded the community edition tarball from [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux%20-%20ideaIC-2022.2.2.tar.gz)
2. Extracted the tarball

on running `./idea.sh` I ran into

```
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Start Failed
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.io.IOException: No locks available
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:96)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:1286)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:1089)
        at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lockPortFiles(SocketLock.java:205)
        at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lockAndTryActivate(SocketLock.java:131)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemDirs(StartupUtil.java:781)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:169)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:119)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:81)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.4+7-b469.53 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
```

---

None of the resolution steps mentioned in this [JetBrains' IntelliJ support article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559) worked for me.

Comment: Is it possible to run Idea as root?

Comment: for me, I just had to kill rubymine with `sudo killall java`

Answer (score 0):

As [the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044391/chaipau) answered in his question:

it worked after he cleared some space in his `/scratch` but he did not dig further what the issue was.